# Can a space be in a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I have just checked the definition of a measure in the MIT's measure theory pdf for the [first lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/lecture-notes/18125_lec1.pdf).

And their $(\sigma_1)$ condition is that $X \in \mathcal{M}$. Where $X$ is a space and $\mathcal M$ is a measure. And I cannot quite understand how space can be an element of measure. I thought that measure is just a function that maps subsets of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\mathcal M$ is not a *measure*. It is a *$\sigma$-algebra*.

Comment: oh dear. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal M$ is not a measure. It is a $\sigma$-algebra.